# NX NestJs - Unexpected error: Error: Unable to load hasher for task "api:serve"

Tags: nestjs, nomachine-nx

i have been trying to follow [these guide](https://www.prisma.io/blog/full-stack-typesafety-with-angular-nest-nx-and-prisma-CcMK7fbQfTWc) to learn NX, but i encounter this problem when i tried to serve the nestJs api
you can see the complete code on [this repo](https://github.com/chenkie/shirt-shop)

```
nx serve api
```

i get these error

```
Error: Unable to resolve @nrwl/node:execute.
Cannot find executor 'execute' in /Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/node/executors.json.
at Workspaces.readExecutor (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/tao/src/shared/workspace.js:92:19)
at getExecutorForTask (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/utils.js:135:22)
at getCustomHasher (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/utils.js:140:25)
at TasksSchedule.<anonymous> (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/tasks-schedule.js:114:62)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at /Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:75
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:16)
at TasksSchedule.hashTask (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/tasks-schedule.js:113:38)
at TasksSchedule.<anonymous> (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/tasks-schedule.js:58:24)

Unexpected error:
Error: Unable to load hasher for task "api:serve"
at getCustomHasher (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/utils.js:145:15)
at TasksSchedule.<anonymous> (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/tasks-schedule.js:114:62)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at /Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:75
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:16)
at TasksSchedule.hashTask (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/tasks-schedule.js:113:38)
at TasksSchedule.<anonymous> (/Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/@nrwl/workspace/src/tasks-runner/tasks-schedule.js:58:24)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at /Users/dariantvirgiesiswadie/Documents/pribadi/shirt-shop/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:75
```

i follow the guide literally 1 to 1, same name and everything.
so i suppose the problem is with my local machine (?) i running macOS 12.2.1 with M1 chip. or maybe these guide using some old version of nx (?) and something changed on the mean time?

so if anyone can give me a clue on this, would be very appreciated. thanks

edit :

i've try to follow the [official Nest with NX](https://nx.dev/nest/overview) demo from their website.
and still got the same error when i try to `nx serve api`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after some digging, it looks like some kind of a bug on the latest (4 March 2022) nx build.
see [this github issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/9168) on nrwl official repo.

According to the comments there, To fix the issue just replace the following executers:

```
"executor": "@nrwl/node:execute" -> "executor": "@nrwl/node:node"
"executor": "@nrwl/node:build" -> "executor": "@nrwl/node:webpack"
```

And that solve my problem too.